# Multiline Title on a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

Is there a way to have a title that consists of two lines on a JFrame?

I've tried:

`JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame("line1\nline2");`

I even thought treating it as JLabel would potentially work, so I did:

`JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame("<html>line1<br>line2<html>);`

Neither work and I tried looking for others who may have had the same question but to no avail. Is this even possible to do in the format that I've outlined?

Comment: No, you cannot. Why would you need to?

Comment: Are you sure that you really need this feature? If so, then one option is to make a headerless JFrame then add your own custom jPanel/TitleBar at the top of the window with a multiline swing component as a label. You would need to implement the icon and buttons and associated methods as well if you want it to look and behave like a normal jFrame titlebar.

Comment: You deleted your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65173855/changing-the-font-of-all-cells-in-a-jtable. Did you solve the problem? If so, then instead of deleting the question add your own answer showing the solution.